# Phonegap Build iOS 7 and 8 Statusbar control

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins

I am trying to control the font color of the iOS 7 & 8 status bar. I am constantly seeing two different plugins being referenced with a slate full of `<preferences/>`. I am hoping someone can shed some light on the difference between the two and which they have had success implementing.

```
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugin.statusbar" /> 
<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance">
  <false/>
</gap:config-file>
```

and

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.statusbar" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
```

I have tried both and can't get the font color to  be light (white). Thank you in advance for any guidance you can give here.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you here but do know the statusbar front did get a nice injection of confusion/chaos w/the iOS8 (possibly even iOS7) - many folks have questions about it: http://goo.gl/8FxkNh. I also share your question/frustration on the preferences inconsistencies and lack of docs around them. I will def be watching your question here for any answers you get.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the value to darkcontent. This is iOS.

The plugin i'm using is

`org.apache.cordova.statusbar`

You should use the correct plugin if you are using phonegap. I'm using **Cordova 3.6**

This is how I get the status bar to act like a "normal" status bar.

`<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="darkcontent" />`

`<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />`

My config.xml:

```
    <feature name="StatusBar">
        <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar" />
    </feature>
    <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
    <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="darkcontent" />
```

Comment: That didn't change anything.

Comment: I did try it. I still get the same dark status bar over my dark header. The one snippet of code that has made any changes was `<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugin.statusbar" version="1.1.0" />
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugin.statusbar" /> 
<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="UIStatusBarHidden">
    <true/>
</gap:config-file>

<gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance">
    <false/>
</gap:config-file>`, but it hides it completely and I just need light font.

Comment: you using cordova 3.6 too right? Because I got this to work easily with just what i've written in the answer. The `gap:plugin` code i think is all for android i'm not sure as i just did this on `iOS`.

Comment: In phonegap build UI it says phonegap 3.6.3. Is there another place to check?

Comment: @AlenGiliana what about the number of `config.xml` files in the project i have 2 and i edit the one in the root inside `platforms/iOS` and run my code from `xcode`. build cmds in terminal at times change the config file, maybe look into that too.

Comment: Here is what I have:   `<widget id="cc.emmanuel.prayer" version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/3.6">`